# Authorize requests with hasIpAddress expression but using IP forwarded from reverse proxy?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using SpringSecurity with SpringBoot and trying to limit access from specific IP addresses. I'm using standard `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasIpAddress('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/16')");` and it works correctly when accessing server directly. But production system is however behing haproxy. We are sending X-Forwarded-For info using haproxy to our app and added these two lines info application.properties

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-Forwarded-For
```

... but still can't access the url. Any idea whats missing or if something must be done differently for checking forwarded remote ip?

Comment: Hi David, do you mind sharing what did you end up doing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to set the

```
server.tomcat.remoteip.remote-ip-header=X-Forwarded-For
```

instead of

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-Forwarded-For
```

property